column splitting /filtering in R and
I have the below sample data frame:
item<-c("A","B")
Type<-c("403P","1200C")

test_df<-data.frame(item, Type)

> test_df
  item  Type
1    A  403P
2    B 1200C

Then I split test_df$Type into 2 columns:
test_df$split_type<-strsplit(test_df$Type, "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)
test_df$split_type<-do.call(rbind, test_df$split_type)|>
  data.frame()|>
  rename(A = X1, B = X2)

New data frame as below:
> test_df
  item  Type split_type.A split_type.B
1    A  403P          403            P
2    B 1200C         1200            C

Try to do filtering with the new data frame:
test_df%>% 
  filter(item=="A")%>%
  select(item,split_type.A)

Below error msg is shown:
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `split_type.A` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

May I ask if anything I did wrong in the splitting process? All comments and ideas are welcomed. Thanks.

The split_type variable in test_df is a data.frame with variables A and B.

Note that test_df$split_type is itself a data frame and not two simple columns in your original data frame.

you have a dataframe embedded in another dataframe. You need to unpack your dataframe.  eg to access column A you have to do test_df$split_type$A. The best way : unpack(test_df, split_type) or even unnest_wider(test_df, split_type) or even unnest_wider(test_df, split_type, names_sep = "."). In this last code, you can now access the column as test_df$split_type.A

You could alternatively do test_df |> tidyr::separate(Type, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])") instead of the strsplit step.

Alternatively, test_df |>   tidyr::separate_wider_regex(Type, c(A = "\\d+", B = "."))

If using base R: do.call(data.frame, test_df) should resolve your problem

Thanks @Jon Spring, I try using ur method and it works perfectly.
> test_df
  item  Type
1    A  403P
2    B 1200C
> test_df<-test_df |> tidyr::separate(Type, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])")
> test_df%>% 
+   filter(item=="A")%>%
+   select(item,A)
  item   A
1    A 403 

